# Components of Angular velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Angular velocity vector is defined as, 
$\overrightarrow{ω} = \widehat{n} \frac{d\theta}{dt}$
where $\widehat{n}$
 is an unit vector along the axis of rotation, and $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is the angular rate at which the particle is turning about the axis of rotation. See figure 1.

Being a vector, $\overrightarrow{\omega}$
can be resolved into components:
$\overrightarrow{\omega} = \omega_x \widehat{i} + \omega_y  \widehat{j} + \omega_z\widehat{k}$

Question: What is the physical interpretation of $\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, and $\omega_z$, other than being the components of $\overrightarrow{\omega}$? Have they got anything to do with the derivatives of the angular displacements 
$\theta_x$, $\theta_y$, and $\theta_z$
of the particle about the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes? See figure 2.
[image: rotation about an axis]![image]

Comment: Review [Euler's  rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem) and the vector composition of infinitesimal rotations.

Comment: The variable $\theta$ is these equations is a scalar, not a vector, so it's not clear what you mean by things like $\theta_x$ as a vector component in the first place.  I kind of get the idea of what you meant (maybe?) from the figures, but what you've drawn, as best I can tell, are not the components of any vector of any sort. You cannot just stack any three numbers you like in a column and call it a vector. In general, rotations are given my matrices, not vectors.

Comment: Think of $\theta_x, \theta_y$ and $\theta_z$ the same way as the pitch, roll and yaw, the rotations about the three axes necessary to bring the particle from its initial position to its current one. Also, I know that these rotations do not commute.

Comment: The problem begins with a page from a mechanics book by kleppner and kolenkow. Initially, they define the angular velocity vector as $\overrightarrow{\omega}= \frac{d\theta_x}{dt} \widehat{i} +\frac{d\theta_y}{dt}\widehat{j} +\frac{d\theta_z}{dt} \widehat{k}$, but on the very next page, they derive the relation $\overrightarrow{v} = \overrightarrow{\omega} ×\overrightarrow{r}$, now they call the quantity $\widehat{n} \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ as $\overrightarrow{\omega}$. This is what got me confused between the two definitions, and I wanted to understand whether the two definitions are same or not.

Comment: Infinitesimal rotations, unlike finite ones, comprise [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Infinitesimal_rotations).